# Format the current date and time using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert the current date and time to in the following way using `moment.js`.

Current date and time using javascript **new Date()**: `Thu Jul 12 2018 09:28:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and want to convert the above format to below mentioned format.

```
 1. Thu, 12 Jul 2018 09:31:37 GMT

 2. 2018-07-12T09:31:38Z
```

Comment: Why not use `moment().toISOString()`?

Comment: moment(new Date()).utc().format();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can learn more about [formatting with moment.js here.](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Escape words in formatting with [escaping-characters "[]".](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters)

```js
console.log(moment());
console.log(moment().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]'));
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try like below for

> 1. nodejs

```
var moment = require('moment');
var format1 = moment().utcOffset(330).format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]')
var format2 = moment().toDate();

console.log(format1);
console.log(format2);
```

> 2. angular

```
import moment from 'moment';
var format1 = moment().utcOffset(330).format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]')
var format2 = moment().toDate();

console.log(format1);
console.log(format2);
```

> Install moment like below

```
npm install --save moment
```

> 3. Html javascript

```
var format1 = moment().utcOffset(330).format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]')

var format2 = moment().toDate();

console.log(format1);

console.log(format2);
```

> moment source script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toGMTSting method to convert local time into GMT format. Hope this helps..

```js
console.log(new Date().toGMTString());
console.log(new Date("Fri Jan 20 2012 11:51:36 GMT-0530").toGMTString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these also:

**`var moment = require('moment')`**;

**`let startDate= new moment('11/22/1990','MM/DD/YYYY').format("YYYY/MM/DD");`**

**You can also understand these:**

```
let otherDate= 1399919400000;
var neweDate = moment(otherDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
//My neweDate output is "13/05/2014";

moment.locale('cs');
console.log(moment.locale()); // en

moment("2010-10-20 4:30",       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");   // parsed as 4:30 local time
moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC
```

**You can verify the date also:**

```
moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false
moment("2010 13",           "YYYY MM").isValid();     // false (not a real month)
moment("2010 11 31",        "YYYY MM DD").isValid();  // false (not a real day)
moment("2010 2 29",         "YYYY MM DD").isValid();  // false (not a leap year)
moment("2010 notamonth 29", "YYYY MMM DD").isValid(); // false (not a real month name)
```

**You can create a Moment with a pre-existing native Javascript Date object.**

```
var day = new Date(2011, 9, 16);
var dayWrapper = moment(day);
```

**You can create a moment with an array of numbers that mirror the parameters passed to new Date()**

```
[year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]

moment([2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]); // February 14th, 3:25:50.125 PM
```

**Any value past the year is optional, and will default to the lowest possible number.**

```
moment([2010]);        // January 1st
moment([2010, 6]);     // July 1st
moment([2010, 6, 10]); // July 10th
```